# OverridePendingTransaction Reverse Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-preferences, android-lifecycle, preferenceactivity

**What I Have**

I have a PreferenceActivity with few preferences. When an user taps a specific preference, another PreferenceActivity will slide in to replace the previous.

**What I Have Done**

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    }
```

This works perfectly and slides the new activity from the right side.

**The Problem**

The reverse animation is not working when I press the back button.

I have tried placing

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
```

in `onStop()` but nothing works.

I need a **way to make the reverse animation work on pressing the back button.**

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
}
```

Comment: Use @override onBackPressed method to track back button of device. and put code inside it